# How to auto follow someone with Twython

Tags: python, tweets, twython

I am making a bot that automatically re-tweets and favorites anything containing the keyword 'Australia'

I am successfully able to re-tweet and favorite the tweet automatically, but I have no idea how to follow them automatically (follow everyone I re-tweet automatically)

```
search_results = twitter.search(q='Australia', count=10)
try:
    for tweet in search_results["statuses"]:
        try:

            twitter.retweet(id = tweet["id_str"])
            twitter.create_favorite(id = tweet["id_str"])
            twitter.create_friendship(user_id=?????)
        except TwythonError as e:
            print (e)
except TwythonError as e:
        print (e)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After lot of trying found this. Try the below

```
twitter = Twython(consumer_key,consumer_secret, access_token, access_secret)
search_results = twitter.search(q='Australia', count=10)
try:
    for tweet in search_results["statuses"]:
        try:
            twitter.retweet(id = tweet["id_str"])
            twitter.create_favorite(id = tweet["id_str"])
            st=tweet["entities"]["user_mentions"]
            if st != []:
                twitter.create_friendship(screen_name=st[0]["screen_name"])
        except TwythonError as e:
            print e
except TwythonError as e:
        print e
```

use `screen_name` to follow the respective handle.

Comment: Oh my gosh that actually worked! Now I need to figure out why it worked! I gave you an upvote and the tick :D